# What is the signature digest for Segwit outputs

Tags: segregated-witness, signature, nbitcoin, p2wpkh, p2wsh

(Assume there's no OP_CODESEPERATOR)

---

For standard P2PKH, the signature digest is generated this way:

NewTransaction

1. settle the TxOuts well
2. set all TxIn scripts to empty
3. insert the **Previous Locking Script** into the TxIn you are signing
4. append hash type code to the end of the transaction
5. SHA256 twice this transaction
6. Be a digest.

---

For standard P2SH, the signature digest is generated this way:

NewTransaction

1. settle the TxOuts well
2. set all TxIn scripts to empty
3. insert the Previous Unlocking Script's **Redeem Script** into the TxIn you are signing
4. append hash type code to the end of the transaction
5. SHA256 twice this transaction
6. Be a digest.

---

I learned those above from [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/File:Bitcoin_OpCheckSig_InDetail.png). As for those above, I have written programs and successfully signed and submitted Bitcoin transactions to the blockchain.

But when it comes to **Segwit**, I don't know what the digest should be. For P2WPKH output, I tried to use the same method to get the digest as P2PKH, but it failed. Blockchain told me my signature was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For signatures in P2WPKH and P2WSH spends, the sighash algorithm is described in BIP143.

It is very different from the one used in legacy spends.